# Let $S^1$ be the group of all complex numbers $w$ such that $|w|=1.$ Show that $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong S^1$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb{Z}$ be the groups of real numbers and integers respectively under addition, and $S^1$ denote the group of complex with modulus $1$ under multiplication.

This question was posted a long time ago here [Group isomorphism: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565552/group-isomorphism-mathbbr-mathbbz-cong-s1), I am attaching an image of it as:[image]

However, I don't understand how to prove this mapping as an injective function. Further, it seems the solution is a little complicated.

I have thought of a proof for it for this problem and hence, I am adding a solution verification tag. My proof goes as follows:

> We have, $1=\cos 0+i \sin 0= \cos\theta +i \sin \theta$ and hence $\theta=0+2n\pi=2n\pi,n\in\Bbb Z$, thus if $e^{2\pi ri}=1$, then $r\in \Bbb Z.$ If we consider a mapping $f:\Bbb R\longrightarrow S^1$ such that $f(r)=e^{2\pi ri}$,$\forall r\in\Bbb R.$ Then, $f$ can be verified as a surjective homomorphism. Now, the identity element in $S^1$ is $1$, so, if $e^{2\pi ir}=1$, then $r\in \Bbb Z.$ Thus $\text{Ker} f=\Bbb Z$, and from 1st Isomorphism theorem, we have $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong S^1.$

I posted this proof because if this is correct, then it becomes a more straight-forward approach than original solutions(atleast according to me.) So, is this proof, correct?

*I dont know whether this is allowed in this site or not, but I didn't post this as a comment on that page because as it seems the user is inactive for ages and I am unlikely to get any response, so I went ahead. Also, I don't mind if moderators decide merging it with the original post.*

Comment: It is injective because for $e^{2i\pi r} = z \in S^1$  with $r \in [0, 2 \pi)$, $e^{2i\pi s } = e^{2i\pi r }$ is equivalent to $r-s \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net How did you know, $r\in[0,2\pi)$  ?

Comment: The map $r \mapsto e^{2i\pi r}$ is a bijection from $[0,2 \pi)$ to $S^1$. Hence such an $r \in [0, 2\pi)$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove the map $f: [r] \mapsto e^{2 \pi i r}$ is injective.  (I assume you've already satisfied yourself that the map is well defined.)

Assume $f([r])=f([s])$.  Then $e^{2 \pi i r}=e^{2 \pi i s}$, so $e^{2 \pi i(r-s)}=1$.  But $e^{2 \pi i (r-s)}= \cos 2 \pi (r-s) + i \sin 2 \pi (r-s)$, so $e^{2 \pi i (r-s)}=1$ means, in particular, that $\cos 2 \pi (r-s) =1$, and that happens only when $r-s \in \Bbb Z$.  That means we're done, because $r-s \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow [r]=[s]$ in $\Bbb R / \Bbb Z$, so $f([r])=f([s]) \Rightarrow [r]=[s]$, proving that $f$ is $1$-$1$.

You also can use the first Isomorphism Theorem to prove the result, as you did in your edit, by demonstrating a surjective homomorphism with $\Bbb Z$ as its kernel.

Comment: Thank you! But if you don't mind , will you please take a look at my now edited question? I have provided a more lucid solution. I will be grateful if you validate it .

Comment: Yes, you can prove the isomorphism by proving that your map is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $\Bbb Z$.  Your proof appears correct to me.

Comment: Thanks a ton! If you add this judgement of my proof in your answer, I will be more than glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1: Proving that $f$ is surjective and injective.

Surjectivity is clear, since every complex number $z$ in $S^1$ is of the form
$$ z=e^{i\theta},$$
where $\theta$ is some real number. If this isn't clear to you look up polar coordinates.

For injectivity, it is enough to show that if there is an $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $e^{2\pi i r}=1$, then $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. This can be seen using polar coordinates.

Variant 2: Constructing an inverse map.

Define $g:S^1\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ by setting $g(e^{2\pi r})=[r]$.
Note that this is well defined because the argument of a complex number is defined up to an integer multiple of $2 \pi i$. Prove that $g$ is inverse to $f$.

Comment: "This can be seen using polar coordinates." :That's what I want to know, how?$e^{2\pi ri}=cos2\pi r+isin2\pi r=1$, But how to conclude it from here? Is it by this:$1=cos 0+isin0=cos\theta +isin\theta$ and hence $\theta=0+2n\pi=2n\pi,n\in\Bbb Z$, thus if $e^{2\pi ri}=1$, then $r\in \Bbb Z$

Comment: Well $e^{2 \pi i r}=1$ implies that $\cos 2 \pi r =1$ and $\sin 2\pi r =0$... Depending on how much you know about the zeros of $\sin$ this implies that $ r \in \mathbb{Z}$. I don't understand your reasoning

Comment: when you say $f$ is injective you don't mean the original $f$ right?

Comment: By $f$ I mean the map $f:\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to S^1,$ given by $f ([r])=e^{2\pi i r}$.